# Информация некорректно отображается в консоли Unubtu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Сообщения с префиксом 'b'\x1b[0m\r отображаются не корректно, наверно это обозначает цвет фона или шрифта. Ubuntu 17.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что вы в ответе ожидаете увидеть? [ANSI код](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) `CSI 0 m` означает reset/normal. `b'\x1b[0m'` это bytes literal в Питоне. Кто-то напечатал текстовое представление байт (как они в исходном коде могут выглядеть), вместо самих байт `len(r"b'\x1b'") == 7` vs. `len(b'\x1b') == 1`

Comment: вот сессии терминалов для сравнения: в одной -- [сами байты выводятся](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYkKR.gif), в другой -- [их текстовое представление](https://i.stack.imgur.com/009XO.gif)